# Selective recursive component recoloring in VB

Tags: vb.net, button, recursion, colors, flat

I've asked a very similar question before, but this time is not about VB syntax, but rather the best approach. I'm making a method that, when passed a component, will recolor it and all components contained within it. Below is the code I have so far, but it is not recoloring all components, instead only a mere few. My main problem is buttons staying in their "3D" styles and not becoming "flat".

```
    If TypeOf comp Is System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase Then
        Dim c As System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase
        c = comp
        c.FlatStyle = Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat
        c.BackColor = getColor(style, PART_BOX)
        c.ForeColor = getColor(style, PART_TEXT)

        comp = c
    End If
```

The component passed is `comp`, and the `getColor` method looks into a database and returns a color corresponding to the `part` parameter passed to the method. This works for all low-level components and all simple components like labels.

[image: This is what happens. As you can see, the colors are fetched and applied properly to many components, but not all.]

As you can see, this is not my preferred outcome. **Does anyone know how to recolor spinners, buttons, and menu bars?** Again, I need the button to end up being *flat*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw your own menu bars. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdk48z0c(v=VS.100).aspx

Buttons have a BackColor property and a FlatStyle property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.flatstyle.aspx

Comment: and what about spinners and buttons?

Comment: I think you'll notice that I already coded in flattening and coloring the button.